# Strip trailing whitespace from files

Tags: shell-script, sed, whitespace

The answer to [removing trailing whitespace with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438306/removing-trailing-whitespace-with-sed/4438318#4438318) has most of the answer, but I want

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' $1
```

to be able to take arbitrary number of file arguments as a shell script on the command line, including glob arguments. I.e. suppose the script is called `strip_trailing_whitespace`. Then I'd like to be able to do both

```
strip_trailing_whitespace foo.cc bar.cc
```

and

```
strip_trailing_whitespace *.cc *.hh
```

to strip trailing whitespaces from all files of the form `*.cc` and `*.hh`. Arguments not based on the answer quoted above are also fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$1` is a [positional parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_01); it will expand to the first argument passed to the script. There are similarly `$2`, `$3`...`$9`, `${10}`, `${11}`,...

The [special parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) `"$@"` will expand to a list of *all* the positional parameters.

So you can do the following:

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' "$@"
```

If you want to pass a glob/pattern to this script (or to any program), it must be escaped or quoted when you call the script - this is a function of the shell; it will expand any patterns before your script even sees it. This case shouldn't need that - the shell can expand the pattern, and the results of that expansion all get passed to `sed`.

Comment: Exactly the same way: `echo "$@"`. Using the parameter doesn't change it in any way, so you can reference `$@` (or any other parameter: positional, special or not) as many times as you want.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after I posted, but was apparently too slow to remove the question. :-)

Comment: keep in mind `-i.bak`, too ... not to mention that sometimes I come across some variant of `sed` without `-i` :) ... +1, still.

Comment: This doesn't work with the version of `sed` that ships with OS X. Instead, install `gnu-sed` (`brew install gnu-sed`) and replace `sed` with `gsed` in the command.

Answer (score 9):

I find it easy to just use sed with xargs as follows:

`find . -name "*.xml" | xargs sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//'`

`find . -type f | grep cc | xargs sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//'`