# Nano - highlight trailing whitespaces

Tags: whitespace, nano, syntax-highlighting

I use `nano` as my standard editor for a file type it has no build in syntax-highlighting for [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org). It is nothing I really need, though I'm missing out quite a lot of white-space characters at the end of lines. Sure I could batch remove them as mentioned here in [Strip trailing whitespace from files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23352/240990).

But it should not be too hard to somehow enable this feature, so I could make a little more clean code from scratch.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Just as `nano` does for shell-scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable this for all filetypes which don't already have syntax highlighting defined by adding the following lines to `.nanorc`:

```
syntax "default"
color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"
```

`syntax "default"` sets the subsequent definitions for default syntax highlighting (i.e., where a filetype hasn't already been matched by some other highlighting definition). `color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"` sets the *background* colour to green for the regex `[[:space:]]+$` - all whitespace at the end of the line. (The colour definition is `<foreground>,<background>` - but whitespace can't show a foreground colour.)

Comment: awesome thanks! sorry for messing with your edit, did not do that on purpose. We just been editing at the same time...

Comment: No worries, I understood that, that's why I re-edited. If I thought it was intentional, I wouldn't have.

Comment: But note that this will remove all preceding `syntax default` options that were set: setting this snippet in your `nanorc` will make all settings from `/usr/share/nano/default.nanorc` ignored.

Comment: [Too late to edit comment] This won't remove preceding colors: `extendsyntax "default" color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"`